# Approaches I can follow to read a list of customers from external system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, ado.net, integration

I am working on a Task Management system using the following technologies:

- Asp.net mvc5.
- Entity framework 6.
- Sql server 2008 R2.

Inside my task management system users will be assigning tasks to related customers. Managing customers (add/edit/delete) is done through our CRM system. The CRM system has a table named Accounts which stores the customer name, customer ID, etc.
I need to read this list of customers inside my asp.net MVC application and build dropdown lists which contain these customers. I know that I can map the CRM database and create a new .edmx file inside my application but I want to avoid coupling my application with the CRM system since loading this list of customers is the only integration point.

I am thinking of the following approach:

- Inside my application create a table named Customers with the following columns; ID (system generated), customerName, ExternalID (the CRM customer ID).
- Write a stored procedure which reads the customers from the CRM system and maps to the SP inside my current application.
- Populate my Customer table with the data returned from the SP.

Following this approach will mean that I will not always have the updated list of customers from the CRM system.  However running the sync job each hour will be enough as customers are quite “slow changing” data.

Can anyone offer advice on this please?

Comment: Those are really your only 2 options (read directly from CRM db or sync the table(s) you need).  The only other possibility that I can think of is to check if the CRM has some sort of API that you could call and populate your drop down.  As to which option is better, its what works for you.  Reading directly from the CRM db will keep your maintenance down however (why aren't new customers showing, oh, the sync process isn't running, etc).  Also, it is recommended to not have this sync process running from the website due to app pool timeouts / recycles.

Comment: @Tommy thanks. First of all the CRM does not provide any API (if it do i would go with this approach). As i mentioned customer does not chnage frequently so a Sync job 4 times a day will be fine, also Admins can run it manually. First question:- can you advice what do you mean by "Reading directly from the CRM db will keep your maintenance down " ? Second question , you mentioned "Also, it is recommended to not have this sync process running from the website due to app pool timeouts" , in my case i will be calling a stored procedure which gets the customers from the CRM ,can u adivce?

Comment: Reading directly from CRM database is exactly what it sounds like. Connect directly to that database and run queries against it. Syncing the data to another database reduces application dependencies and allows you to not have the CRM database accessible to a site on the internet. However, Tommy's point is that you're then reliant on the sync process, which could break or otherwise stop working, leaving you with stale data. As far as not running the sync from the website, Tommy just means that this should be done via an external process, such as a SQL job running an SSIS package.

Comment: so you are with the approach of directly reading the CRM database per request to build the customer drop down lists inside my system? of course this will guarantee that users will get the latest data regarding the customers, but at the same time if the CRM system is dawn or we want to buy a new system, then all the views which have the drop down list will stop working.. so that why i prefer to have a sync job , and to read the customer data from my own DB, as in this case if the CRM is down or is replaced, my views which have the customer drop down list will still work. so what do you think?

Comment: Create a web service based on the service facade design pattern that links to the CRM database. Use this service to populate the drop down.